Show that it is Np-hard to determine whether a given graph has the crossing number k
I want to prove that this problem to find whether the crossing number of any given graph is K or not, is NP-Hard. I don't know how to do this. Can someone help me with this ?

Are you familiar with reductions? Yes: please specify where exactly you are stuck or state your doubt. No: please go through a standard textbook/material on proving NP-completeness first.

The crossing number problem is well studied; a simple web search would have revealed that. Here's one (probably original) proof: https://doi.org/10.1137/0604033

The crossing number problem has been well studied. From wiki:

In general, determining the crossing number of a graph is hard; Garey and Johnson showed in 1983 that it is an NP-hard problem [ref].


In fact the problem remains NP-hard even when restricted to cubic graphs [ref2] and to near-planar graphs (graphs that become planar after removal of a single edge) [ref3].

Also see this stackexchange discussion.
